# Dummies to factors (in data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

In a data frame, I want to turn a group of variables, currently representing dummies, to a single categorical variable. For example, in my data I have several variable representing geographical regions:

```
City    North  Centre  South
----------------------------
Milan       1       0      0
Rome        0       1      0
Naples      0       0      1
Venice      1       0      0

df <- structure(list(City = c("Milan", "Rome", "Naples", "Venice"), 
North = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Centre = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), South = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("City", "North", "Centre", "South"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to change it to:

```
City    Region
--------------
Milan    North
Rome    Centre
Naples   South
Venice   North
```

I can create the variable `Region` with `dplyr` with the following commands:

```
df %>% mutate(Region = case_when(
                      .$North==1 ~ "North", .$Centre==1 ~ "Centre", .$South==1 ~ "South"))
```

I wonder how to do the same with `date.table`, which I am currently learning, given that the function `case_when` is not available. I am looking for a similar one line solution.

Comment: No need for packages at all `names(dat[-1])[max.col(dat[-1])]` or `dat[, .(City, Region=names(dat)[max.col(.SD)]), .SDcols=-1]` if you want to massage it to data.table specifically

Comment: using `ifelse` : `dt[,Region:=ifelse(North==1,"North",ifelse(Centre==1,"Centre","South"))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for packages at all:

```
names(dat[,-1])[max.col(dat[,-1])]
#[1] "North"  "Centre" "South"  "North"
```

If you want to massage it to data.table specifically

```
dat[, .(City, Region=names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)]), .SDcols=-1]
#     City Region
#1:  Milan  North
#2:   Rome Centre
#3: Naples  South
#4: Venice  North
```

If speed is absolutely critical:

```
dat[, names(.SD)[Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, .SD, seq_along(.SD)))], .SDcols=-1]
```

Comment: How can I modify this solution if I want to indicate columns/variables with dummies by their names rather than by their position?

Comment: I'm guessing max.col is plenty fast / the fastest possible, but there's also `for (col in c("North", "Centre", "South")) df[.(1), on=col, v := col][]`. Btw, any reason not to use `:=` to add it as a column?

Comment: @Massimo2013 - you can reference names too - `.SDcols=-c("City","North")` to drop `North` as well, or without the `-` to include rather than exclude.

Comment: Ok, I came to this: `cols=c("North","Centre","South")` and then: `dt[,Region:=factor(cols[max.col(.SD)]),.SDcols=cols]`

Comment: Just for completeness, I was wondering how can `dep.max` (as an alternative to `case_when`) be used within `dplyr`. It is not obvious to me how we refer to a subset of columns within a `mutate` function